# Session ID changes on saved to DB

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have this small problem on Session. Ill show you the codes below.

```
//checking session orderid if not created  
$setSession = $_SESSION['neworderid'];
if (empty($setSession)) {
    $neworderid = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);  
    $_SESSION['neworderid'] = $neworderid;
}

//check if order_id exists in the database  
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM mn_orderitems WHERE order_id =" . $_SESSION['neworderid']);  
$query = $db->loadResult();  
if (!empty($query)) {  
    //if exists, do nothing  
    echo 'Not Empty';  
} else {
    //if order id doesn't exist, save the new order item  
    $qry = "INSERT INTO mn_orderitems (order_id, product_id, orderitem_name, orderitem_quantity, orderitem_price, orderitem_final_price) VALUES
        ('" . $_SESSION['neworderid'] . "', '" . $item->product_id . "', '" . $item->orderitem_name . "', '" . $item->orderitem_quantity . "', '" . $item->orderitem_price . "', '" . $item->orderitem_final_price . "')";  
    $result = mysql_query($qry);  
    if (!$result) {  
        echo "Error";  
    } else {  
        echo "Saved";  
    }  
    echo 'Empty';  
}
```

Problem:
"When I try to echo the `$_SESSION['neworderid']`; it `outputs = 8152269414`
But when it is being save to database the `order_id` changes to 2147483647".

This only happens in live server. No problem in my localhost Apache.

Comment: Is this a legacy app? You really shouldn't be using `mysql_query` for new code, it's deprecated, being removed from PHP, and leads to severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you forget to [escape your values properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: your order id is random, but  is not guaranteed to be unique, why not use the auto incremented id, its a lot safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is not with the PHP script itself, but your database structure. In MySQL the biggest number you can store (declared as INT) is 2147483647. If you want to store bigger numbers, you'll have to either change the script to generate a lower number OR change the DB to use BIGINT.

Answer (score 0):

Change first order_id's structure in phpMyAdmin from **INT** into **BIGINT**

```
/* checking session orderid if not created  */

session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['neworderid'])) {
    $neworderid = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);  
    $_SESSION['neworderid'] = $neworderid;
    $setSession = $_SESSION['neworderid'];
}

else {

$setSession = $_SESSION['neworderid'];

}

/* check if order_id exists in the database and convert the code to mysqli */
/* have your connection store into $db variable */
$result=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM mn_orderitems WHERE order_id ='$setSession'");  

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=0) {  
    /* If a record has been found, do nothing */
    echo "Not Empty";  
} else {

    /* if order id doesn't exist, save the new order item */

    $insert=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO mn_orderitems (order_id, product_id, orderitem_name, orderitem_quantity, orderitem_price, orderitem_final_price)
    VALUES ('$setSession', '$product_id', '$orderitem_name', '$orderitem_quantity', '$orderitem_price', '$orderitem_final_price')");  

    if($insert){
    echo "Successfully Added item no. ".$setSession;
    }

}
```